# Android Studio not showing Firebase Authentication SDK documentation

Tags: android-studio, firebase-authentication

Android Studio is not showing the documentation of firebase authentication sdk as shown below

[image]

Clicking on **Edit API docs paths** does nothing.
Clicking on **External documentation for ...** works for some methods and classes but not for all